# Custom decoding a byte array

Tags: python, struct, decode, python-2.x, pyserial

I have a python code which is reading serial data. The format in which it comes is:

```
e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff
```

What is actually supposed to be stored here is the **id** of a specific component which was selected on the hardware device that I am accessing via serial. The type of the **id** I believe is integer, because it is auto-generated, I can not change it and it gets values like 1, 2, 3, etc... for each component (button).

My serial is configured like that:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',baudrate=9600,timeout=1.0)
```

So, if I clicked a button with id of `1` I would get => 
e\x00`\x01`\x01\xff\xff\xff

If I clicked a button with id of `2` => 
e\x00`\x02`\x01\xff\xff\xff

and if the id was `10` => 
e\x00`\x0A`\x01\xff\xff\xff

The ending symbols `\xff\xff\xff` are always there and the starting `e`.

My question is: **How can I read such input in a consistent way and extract this bit of the whole array which brings value to me?** From what I saw in the internet, I could use Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) package and unpack such a thing (`e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff`) but in order to do that I need to know/define its format somehow.

What I'd like to be able to read are the first two integers (hex encoded) after the `e`.

Comment: Could you please try `type(output)` on your data? Is it `bytes`?

Comment: <class 'bytes'> it is

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @parasit's got the right idea, but I would formalize things bit more and use code similar to the following. The initial `x` [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) in the `struct` format string `DAT_FMT` means ignore the first byte of the data (the `e` in the sample serial data).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import struct

DAT_FMT = 'x6B'

for sample in (b'e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff',
               b'e\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff\xff',
               b'e\x00\x01\x0a\xff\xff\xff'):

    dat0, dat1, id, dat3, dat4, dat5 = struct.unpack(DAT_FMT, sample)
    print(dat0, dat1, id, dat3, dat4, dat5, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255
0, 1, 2, 255, 255, 255
0, 1, 10, 255, 255, 255
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am quite new to python so could you please just clarify what is the role of DAT_FMT? What does it say written like this?

Comment: user2128702: It just a coding convention of using all UPPERCASE names for variables that are really constants (i.e. their values don't vary). This and many other excellent suggestions are in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which I strongly suggest you read and follow as much as possible. Doing so will make your code more readable (and obviously more uniform if everyone's following them).

Comment: P.S. Another suggestion I'd like to make is for you to upgrade to Python 3.x if that's feasible. Not much sense learning stuff that's already outdated if you don't have to — plus improvements to the language would have allowed me to make the code in this answer a little more succinct and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this helps you:

```
from struct import *
unpack('xbbbbbb','e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff')
(0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff` is a `bytes` object. Notice the leading `b` when you initialize it. You don't need `struct` to access it.

Just access the individual characters by using their index in the array:

```
x = b'e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff'
print(x[0]) # this is the 'e', it's 101 in ascii
print(x[1])
print(x[2]) # this is the value of your button
print(x[3]) 
print(x[4]) 

x = b'e\x00\x0A\x01\xff\xff\xff'
print(x[2]) # now the value of the button is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is represented as a string or you can easily get it to one, simply split it by the '\' character and access [1] and [2] indexes to get them.

```
s = r"e\x00\x01\x01\xff\xff\xff".split(r"\x") # r prefixed the string to avoid having to escape the backslashes
int1 = int(s[1], 16) # the second argument is the base, here, hexadecimal
int2 = int(s[2], 16)
print(int1) # 2
print(int2) # 1
```

If it's a byte object, you can already access it with indexes. Just

```
print(s[1])
print(s[2])
```

to get the values you need

Comment: `s` missing in the last example.